# mysql lock table join not work

Tags: mysql, locking

Can work

```
$this->db->query('LOCK TABLE user READ');
$this->db->query('select * from user');
$this->db->query('UNLOCK TABLES');
```

It's not working

```
$this->db->query('LOCK TABLE company READ');
$this->db->query('select * from user as a join company as b on a.id=b.id where a.id = 1');
$this->db->query('UNLOCK TABLES');
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: You sure there is a case where b.id=1?

Comment: Yes,have a simple example